# Clickatell - WhatsApp Template - One API

Tags: templates, whatsapp, clickatell

I try to send a [WhatsApp template message](https://www.clickatell.com/products/whatsapp/) using the [Clickatell One API](https://platform.clickatell.com/v1/message)  end point.

Here is my payload. I'm send this against the endpoint with `POST`.

```
{
    "messages":[
       {
          "to":"***********",
          "channel": "whatsapp",
          "hsm" : {
             "template":"welcome_notification_demo",
             "parameters" : {
                "1":"John",
                "2":" Clickatell"
             }
          }
       }
    ]
 }
```

I receive the following response from them:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "error": {
                "code": 23,
                "description": "Invalid or missing parameter: HSM ."
            },
            "accepted": false,
            "to": "*********"
        }
    ],
    "error": null
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing in my payload?
(The documentation is not at all useful.)

Note: I used ********** to hide my phone number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the support team:

*"The cause of the error is that you are attempting to send a Default Whatsapp Template from a verified Whatsapp Business Number. Please retest by using one of your approved custom templates and advise us if the issue continues."*

So I tried with one of our custom templates and **it worked!**

(Would be nice if the documentation mentioned that you can't test with a default template)